# How can send http request to Webdriver endpoint?

Tags: python, http, webdriver

I'am trying to send HTTP request to Chrome Webdriver endpoint in python using native HTTPConnection methods, The connection get established but the request method does not work.
Note: when i use postman everything works fine.

```
import http.client
import json

connection = http.client.HTTPConnection("http://localhost:9515")
headers = {"Content-type" : "application/json"}
json_data = json.dumps({
    "capabilities " : {
        "browsername" : "chrome",
        "browserVersion" : "12"
    }
})
connection.request("POST", "/session", json_data, headers)
response = connection.getresponse()
connection.close()
```

```
PS C:\Users\Coder\Desktop\Ayman\automation> python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Coder\Desktop\Ayman\automation\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    connection.request("POST", "/session", json_data, headers)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1282, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 975, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 941, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\socket.py", line 824, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\socket.py", line 955, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: Try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed `http://` part of the host argument, and now it works fine.

```
connection = http.client.HTTPConnection("localhost:9515")
```